# Skewed poll results?

Tags: statistics, average

I have an asignment:

> Students on various universities were given polls where they rated
> their school on a scale:
>
> 1. Very bad
> 2. Far below average
> 3. Below average
> 4. Average
> 5. Above average
> 6. Far above average
> 7. Excellent
>
> After evaluating the individual averages for each university, they computed an average of those and the
> result was $4.94$.
>
> This means that most of the universities are above average.
>
> What dou you think of that?

My first thought is that there's a problem with the way the data is presented.

Instead of taking the average of all the answers, they first computed an average of each university individually and then they computed average of these averages.

Is it a problem though?

Let $s_k$ be the number of students at the $k$-th university and $u$ the number of universities.
When I take a regular average, I get:
$$ S = \sum_{i = 1}^{u} s_k $$

$$\overline{x} = \frac{1}{S} \sum_{i = 1}^{S} x_i $$

but when I take the average of averages:
$$\overline{y} = \frac{1}{u} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{u}\frac{1}{s_k} \sum_{i = 1}^{s_k} y_i \right).$$

But $\overline{x} \neq \overline{y}$.

Would it be a fair evaluation if they took weighted average instead? Would $s_k$ be a fair weight?

Comment: As you've shown, they'll compute different things, but that may or may not be desirable. Do you want the average rating among students, or the average rating among universities? The former might be better if you want to look at overall student satisfaction, the latter might be better if there's big differences in response rate between universities. Regardless, the effect that more than 50% of people rate themselves as "above average" by whatever metric you can think of is quite common, so it's not much of a surprise here.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Exactly. It really depends on the situation. If the goal was to evaluate how satisfied students are with their universities, I would just simply take an average of those answers (but there still should be some correction but I don't know which), however, if we wanted to know how the universities are doing on average, I would take weighted average to account for different number of participants at each university.

Comment: If better universities are larger, then the average student should be expected to go to an above average university.  This is a curiosity but no worse than a child's expected  family size being above the average size of families

Comment: @Henry Interesting point. Another similar effect is seen seen in social networks - your friends will, on average, have more friends than you do, since people with many friends are over-represented in pool of people you might be friends with.